# Problem related to Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $\alpha$ have the minimal polynomial $x^2 + x+1 =0$  over $\mathbb Q$ , I have to find the expression of the element $\frac {\alpha^2 +1}{\alpha^2 -1}$ in the form $a+b\alpha$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb Q $ .

We have $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0 $ , also

$\frac {\alpha^2 +1}{\alpha^2 -1}$ = ${\alpha \over \alpha - 1} - \frac {1}{\alpha + 1}$ , I can't move further, **Any help!**

Thank you ..

Answer (score 3):

The gcd of $x^2 + x + 1$ and $x^2 - 1$ is $1$ and you have
$$1 = \frac{1}{3} (x-1) (x^2 - 1) - \frac{1}{3}(x-2) (x^2 + x + 1)$$
Plugging in $\alpha$ makes the second summand zero, so you have $$1 = \frac{1}{3} (\alpha - 1) (\alpha^2 - 1) $$
In other words 
$$ \frac{1}{\alpha^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{3}(\alpha -1)$$
It follows that 
$$ \frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha^2 -1} = \frac{1}{3}(\alpha^2 +1)(\alpha -1)$$
which you can expand and simplify using the relation $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You could write $\alpha=-\frac12(1+i\sqrt3)$ and use the usual
arithmetic of complex numbers.

Alternatively
$$\frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha^2-1}=\frac{-\alpha}{-\alpha-2}.$$
You need to find real $x$ and $y$
with
$$\alpha=(x+y\alpha)(\alpha+2).$$
You can expand this out, using $\alpha^2=-\alpha-1$ to get
two linear equations for $x$ and $y$.